# HP Spectre x360 Incorrect Touch firmware flashed

Tags: laptop, drivers, flash, touchscreen, hp-spectre

I accidently updated my HP touchscreen driver or ROM to another one. I wanted to update it, which caused a bug because it was of wrong version then I found a fake solution which just messed up everything. Long story short now I am stuck with a hardware having incorrect firmware.

Laptop: HP Spectre x360 13-ae524tu

I have tried almost everything I could find on the Internet, I have been looking for a solution since OCT 2020.

Similar Problem: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Video-Display-and-Touch/Flashed-wrong-Touch-firmware-and-even-not-working-after-lcd/m-p/6873388

I tried finding the contact of that guy the one having similar problem but am unable to.

What was the incorrect thing that I installed
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10CMHpUjC3Dh9A2AVVqVipwOJnlXfrXLi/view?usp=sharing
This I found somewhere on internet (again a mistake I should never ever repeat) I installed it. probably force update was enabled, and after that I am not able to install any of the firmware updates provided by HP or even in the link above.

I get this error
[Error on installing or trying to update firmware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvmPt.png)

The log for installation that caused the problem: https://pastebin.com/mhxN6SiM

[Driver Installed after the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o46mZ.png)

**So My conclusion is:** I flashed a wrong firmware update which changed the HID or some settings. So now I need a way to flash the correct version which seems to be https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-spectre-13-4100-x360-convertible-pc/8499273/model/9216215 Firmware -> HP FullHD Touchscreen Controller Firmware Update